How to solve this infimum problem? What is the relationship between infimum and limit?
Problem setting: $x\in\mathcal{X}$  is variable vector, $\mathcal{X}$ is a closed set; $p, u$ are parameter vectors, and they have the same dimension. Let $\mathcal{A}=\{x:u^{\top}x>0, \forall x\in \mathcal{X}\}$,  and $p^{\top}x >0 ,\forall x\in \mathcal{A}$.
We assume, for all $x\in\mathcal{A}$, there does not exist a path such that along this path $x_n\rightarrow \hat{x}$ and $p^{\top} \hat{x} = 0$, and there exists another path such that along this path $x_n \rightarrow \hat{x}$ and $u^{\top}\hat{x} = 0$. Since $u^{\top}p = 0$, they are two different paths. Then, What is the infimum, $\inf\limits_{x\in\mathcal{A}}\frac{p^{\top}x}{u^{\top}x}$? Does it exist? Could it be zero?
Try: There are two possible cases. Firstly, the infimum is obtained at some $x_1 \in \mathcal{A}$, which does not tend to $\hat{x}$, since $\mathcal{X}$ is closed, $u^{\top} x$ is bounded above, and $p^{\top} x_1 >0$, the infimum is a positive value.
Secondly, the infimum is obtained at a sequence $x_n \rightarrow \hat{x}$. However, since we can find a path such that $u^{\top} x_n = 0$, the limit does not exist (multi-variable L'Hopital's Rule), then the infimum neither exists, since in this case, infimum is the limit value.
Above all, the infimum is a positive value.
Question: Am I right? Is the existence of infimum in the second case equivalent to that of limit?
